# Rendering a still image (not animation) with motion blur

Tags: motion-blur

I want to simulate the camera shake while taking a photo and see the result. Everything works fine, but I have to create an animation and then try to render the image of an specific frame in order to see the motion blur caused by camera shake.
Actually I don't need the animation because my job is working with images. So is there any way that I won't have to create multiple frame animations in order to render desired image?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you animate the camera? You don't have to render the entire animation, just the frame you're interested in. And it'll give you ultimate control over the exact camera motion blur you want.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. But in my mind it would make my process more specific if I just render an image instead of an animation. If there is a way it would be more properiate for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need to create an animation?
Because you need transformation, both in space and time.

For motion blur to exist there has to be a notion of before and after. An object (or the camera) was in one place in frame 1

[image]

and is in a different place in frame 3.

[image]

Depending on the distance the objects moved, and the shutter speed set in the motion blur settings, you might see the movement in frame two represented as a blurred image.

[image]

You certainly don't need to render an animation (frames 1, 2 and 3) you can render just frame 2 and the motion blur should be there as a still image.

Notice that in this example even in frames 1 and 3 there is some motion blur because of the magnitue of the transformation from frame to frame(relative to the shutter speed).

If we were to render frame 0 and 4 the cube would appear static because there is no transformation from frame to frame anymore.

[image]

[image]